# Run window onLoad inside a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

The problem I am encountering is that I want to run `window` onload inside a function, but the `alert` command does not show up. Why?

```
function table1() {
    $(window).on("load", function() {
        alert('It Works!'); 
    }); 
} // end method
```

Comment: Maybe you never call `table1` function?

Comment: onload is a event itself..You can not determine when to fire that event..

Comment: why not call table1 function in window.onload rather than the other way round?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? What you've written will basically only set up the onload event handler when you call the function table1. This will probably be too late for the event handler to ever be triggered, since the window load event will already have fired.

Comment: What I am trying to achieve is to be able to run 5 different diagrams by calling them by table1(), table2() etc. JQuery will handle the logic and whenever the user selects a diagram, the diagram will prompt up. So the `alert` command is going to be replaced by the diagram.

Answer (score 0):

write onload function outside table1(). You cannot call onload function explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to assign window onload to another variable and call it in your table1() event.

```
var wload = window.onload;

function table1(){
    wload();

    alert("It Works!");
}
```